# Проверка уникальности вводимого значения

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем доброго дня. Сразу скажу, что python первый мой язык и я только начинаю его изучать, так что вопросы могут показаться очень глупыми.
Есть вот такой скрипт:

```
import json
import re
import string
 
 
while True:
    print("1. Добавить новую запись пользователя")
    print("2. Добавить организацию")
    print("3. Поиск по записям")
    print("0. выйти из программы")
    cmd = input("Выберите пункт: ")
 
 
if cmd == "1":
  print ("Ввод данных")

  data = {}
  
  flag = True
  while flag:
      if "ID" in data:
          print ("ID существует")
          flag = False
          break
      else:
          try:
             data["ID"] = int(input("Введите ID: "))
             flag = False
          except:
             print("Вводимое в ID должно быть целым числом!")


  
  print ("Введите ФИО")

  data["Name"] = input()

  print ("Введите email")
  
  data["Email"] = input()

  print ("Введите номер телефона")

  data["Phone"] = input()

  print ("Введите ID компании")
  data["companyID"] = input()
  

  with open("users.json", "a+") as file:
           file.write('\n')
           json.dump(data, file,ensure_ascii=False )


elif cmd == "2":
  print ("Ввод данных")

  data = {"companyID": ''}
  
  while (not data["companyID"].isdigit()):
      data = {"companyID": input('Введите ID компании: ')}
      if (not data["companyID"].isdigit()): 
          print('ID необходимо указать цифрами!')
          
  
  print ("Введите название компании")

  data["Name"] = input()

  print ("Введите email")
  
  data["Email"] = input()

  print ("Введите номер телефона")

  data["Phone"] = input()
  

  with open("users.json", "a+") as file:
           file.write('\n')
           json.dump(data, file,ensure_ascii=False )



elif cmd == "3":
    while True:
        print("1. Поиск по пользователям")
        print("2. Поиск по организациям")
        cmd = input("Выберите пункт: ")
        if cmd == "1":
          print ("Введите ID пользователя")
          w = input("Введите ID : "   )
          with open("Users.json") as fin:
              for s in fin.readlines():
                 if s.find(w) > -1:
                   print(s.strip())
                   
        elif cmd == "2":          
            print ("Введите ID компании")
            w = input("Введите ID : "   )
            with open("Users.json") as fin:
                for s in fin.readlines():
                   if s.find(w) > -1:
                     print(s.strip())


elif cmd == "0":
                break
```

Как корректно сделать запрет на создание дублей в поле ID. Допустим при создании пользователя вводится значение ID которое уже есть в данном файле у другого пользователя, надо что бы появлялось сообщение что ID уже существует и дальше пользователя не пускает.
Сейчас эта часть выглядит вот так

```
flag = True
  while flag:
      if "ID" in data:
          print ("ID существует")
          flag = False
          break
      else:
          try:
             data["ID"] = int(input("Введите ID: "))
             flag = False
          except:
             print("Вводимое в ID должно быть целым числом!")
```

Оно не отрабатывает как нужно. Формат записи в файле выглядит вот так

```
{"ID": 1, "Name": "Тестовый пользователь", "Email": "test@test.test", "Phone": "+79998884455", "companyID": "1"}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, чтобы вам могли помочь что означает "Оно не отрабатывает как нужно".

Comment: `Формат записи в файле выглядит вот так` - а должен выглядеть как?

Comment: Не происходит ничего - если запустить и ввести ID, который уже есть в файле, скрипт всё равно его создаст с таким же ID не выдав никаких предупреждений.

Comment: если `ID` это то что я думаю - просто уникальное значение записи в файле, то этим должен заниматься не пользователь а сама программа, не стоит пользователям доверять такое.

Comment: Задача по скрипту стоит такая, что ID вбивается ручками и проверяется при этом на уникальность самим скриптом(

Comment: Вы собрались написать собственную БД? Зачем изобретать велосипед после автомобиля? Посмотрите на sqlite хотя-бы

Comment: в таком случае нужно читать `json файл`, правда в данном формате его нужно будет приводить к массиву (так как это не валидный json, там может быть или объект или массив, а у Вас там куча объектов но не в массиве) а после искать в нем соответсвующую запись по введенному ID если таковой нет - ID валидный. Чтобы сделать валидный json нужно, после каждой строки поставить `,` и поместить в скобки  `[  все строки  ]`

Comment: Думаю, что лучше воспользоваться советом @Namerek т.е. готовой БД. Хотя если Вы делаете это в учебных целях можете попробовать со своим велосипедом. Если эта программа должна кем-то использоваться то я бы трижды подумал : 1)только представьте пользователя который пытается угадать какого id нет, 2) искать всегда проще не по id а по имени или названию, 3) файл json должен быть полноценным, чтобы не делать с ним чудеса каждый раз.

Comment: Это скрипт в учебных целях, к которому каждый раз добавляют новые задачи. Сейчас задача именно на проверку уникальности вводимого значения ID.  И я пока даже близко не понимаю как сделать проверку уникальность при вводе, что бы  не пускать пользователя дальше, пока он не введет уникальный ID.

Comment: Так как ответ уже получен, могу лишь добавить что в Вашем случае нужно хорошенько продумывать возможность расширяемости программы, да и вообще об этом не лишне задумываться чтобы каждый раз больше дописывать чем переписывать в предоставленном ответе такая расширяемость есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По мотивам Вашего вопроса.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import json
from typing import Dict, Any, List, Optional

users: List[Dict[str, Any]]


db_json = Path().joinpath('db.json')
if db_json.exists():
    users = json.load(
        db_json.open('r', encoding='utf-8')
    )

else:
    users = []

exists = [item.get('ID') for item in users]
last_id = max(exists or [0])


def check_id(uid: str) -> Optional[int]:
    if not isinstance(uid, str):
        return
    elif isinstance(uid, str) and not uid.isnumeric():
        return

    elif int(uid) in exists:
        print(
            'Вы пытаетесь использовать занятый ID'
        )
        return
    return int(uid)

prompt = 'Пожалуйста введите ID: '
while not (user_id := check_id(input(prompt))):
    prompt = f'Рекомендуемый ID {last_id + 1}: '

user = [("ID", user_id)]

for title, name in [
    ("ФИО", "Name"),
    ("email", "Email"),
    ("номер телефона", "Phone"),
    ("ID компании", "companyID"),
]:
    user.append(
        (name, input(f"Введите {title}: "))
    )

users.append(
    dict(user)
)

json.dump(
    users,
    db_json.open('w', encoding='utf-8'),
    ensure_ascii=False,
    indent=2
)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @bazilio57, Да не за что. Обращайтесь.